# How to index single element in ndarray using list?

Tags: python, numpy

I'm starting to learn numpy and can't understand the very basic thing. I have a list of indexes
in a multidimensional array (one for each axis). How can I set the value to the point in an array that corresponds to that index? Basically, how can I use idxs variable in the folllowing code and produce same result?

```
A = np.zeros((2, 2))
idxs = [1, 0]
A[1, 0] = 1
A
```

array([[0., 0.],
[1., 0.]])

Comment: `A[0,1]` is equivalent to `A[(0,1)]`,, not `A[[0,1]]`

Comment: `A[tuple(idxs)] = 1`

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Ivan,

```
A[tuple(idxs)] = 1
```

works